# Stored procedure GET

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Maybe this is a obvious question, but I have a problem with my code to get the information of the database table. For example, I have two tables called `Productos` & `Proveedores`. I created a stored procedure to obtain the data of one table to show with API, but (PostMan Software) when I use

```
GET http://localhost:4716/api/Proveedor    show me "null"
```

Here is the code for the SQL Server stored procedure:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name =         'SP_GetProd')
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE SP_GetProd
END
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GetProd
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TblProducto] 
END
GO
```

and for sure I create other procedure for `Proveedores`:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name =     'SP_GetProve')
BEGIN
     DROP PROCEDURE SP_GetProve
END
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GetProve
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TblProveedores]
END
GO
```

In C# Code I have this to call the methods:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromBody] Productores.Models.Producto prod)
 { 
            Productores.Productores o_prod = new Productores.Productores(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqlCnn"].ToString());
            o_prod.obtener(prod);
            o_prod.Dispose();
            return Request.CreateResponse<Productores.Models.Producto>(HttpStatusCode.Created, prod);
 }

/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/

public void obtener (Models.Producto objProducto)
{
        try
        {
            CreateConnection();
            mSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            mSqlCommand.Connection = mSqlConnection;
            mSqlCommand.CommandText = "SP_GetProd";
            mSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            mSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

I am out of ideas... can anybody help me please?

Comment: fisrt, you sure that your conenction is correct ?

Comment: put breakpoints in your code and make sure that you are connecting properly, make sure that the database you are connecting to has the stored procedure what is the default database that your connection string is connecting to.. what's the connection string look like

Comment: The connection is not the problem, i can connect to the database without problem, and in the database exist the SP_GetProve and SP_GetProd, but when i send the API with Postman shows me null...

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is not the correct method to retrieve data from your tables, This method is used for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE calls not for a SELECT. It executes the stored procedure, but it doesn't return the data from the table. Usually the `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of records affected by the query but in this context is not clear what is the return value.

You need to use an [`ExecuteReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader(v=vs.110).aspx) call, but then you need to provide a List of `Producto` because you are not limiting the results with some kind of WHERE condition and thus, `ExecuteReader` will return every single record from your table. If this is what you want you need to change your code to

```
public void obtener (List<Models.Producto> prods)
{
    try
    {
        CreateConnection();
        mSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        mSqlCommand.Connection = mSqlConnection;
        mSqlCommand.CommandText = "SP_GetProd";
        mSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Here the SP will be executed and the result is ready
        using(SqlDataReader reader = mSqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Move the reader on the first/next record until there are records
            while(reader,Read())
            {
                 // Create one empty Producto 
                 Models.Producto aSingleProd = new Models.Producto();

                 // Set every property of the Producto with the 
                 // values from the fields returned by the SP
                 aSingleProd.Property1 = reader["Field1"].ToString();
                 .... other property of your Producto
                 prods.Add(aSingleProd);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

As a side note, please do not handle the connection and the command in this way. Better use local variables and after using them dispose them (like I have done in the `SqlDataReader` case). If you keep global objects like in your example you will have problems Handling the state of the connection and in disposing it when you don't need it anymore.

The last problem is the name of the stored procedure. Better not use the prefix SP because Microsoft has stated that this prefix is reserved for the system stored procedure and albeit improbable there is the possibility of conflicts with Microsoft defined stored procedure for the system

Answer (score 0):

In your above sutiation you need to use `ExecuteReader`

### ExecuteNonQuery

> ExecuteNonQuery method will return number of rows effected with
>   INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE operations. This ExecuteNonQuery method will
>   be used only for insert, update and delete, Create, and SET
>   statements.

[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

### ExecuteReader

> Execute Reader will be used to return the set of rows, on execution of
>   SQL Query or Stored procedure using command object. This one is
>   forward only retrieval of records and it is used to read the table
>   values from first to last.

[SqlCommand.ExecuteReader MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx)

### Execute Scalar

> Execute Scalar will return single row single column value i.e. single
>   value, on execution of SQL Query or Stored procedure using command
>   object. It’s very fast to retrieve single values from database.

[SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Marco,
It appears that you are running .Dispose on the `o_prod` object then trying to get some results out of it.  It's not a great answer, but try commenting out the line `o_prod.Dispose()`

Also one other thing is that you aren't assigning the results to anything in your obtener function.